# Can I move a Node Pug Template into the dist folder and load contents dynamically?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pug, babeljs, parcel

I'm using *parcel* and *babel*. For the client-side I have used React. In server-side I have used Node Express.

Previously I load `main.html` file by a router call and send it to the client as `res.sendFile(main.html)`. It worked as React Entry point.

But now I have to use a *template (Pug)* instead of `main.html` since I have to load a dynamic javascript in client-side. So I replace the **main.html file with the main.pug** file and move it to the dist folder by parcel build.

Now I am trying to load dynamic content into that pug template which situated inside `/dist` folder. **Is it possible to do such a thing because once I build the project, `/dist/main.pug` file doesn't have `"{}"` these place holders?**. I know `/dist` folder contains static files. In that case is they're any way to achieve this scenario?

I tried to load `views/main.pug` file but in that case React libraries were not loading and gave me

> can not use import outside of the module.

I tried other answers given to that question but not worked. So I decided to move `main.pug` into the `/dist`. Now React libraries are loading but not dynamic contents.

Comment: I know I can achieve this by two router calls. But is there any way to do this without two router calls??

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I decided to use `views/main.pug` file and load the relevant script client-side. Once it loads on the client side, there is a new request to my new server route and it delivers the `public/main.html`. This approach results in one extra call to the server.